# How to use multi threading to fetch data in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

Hi I am trying to fetch 50K + rows from one of the table in MYSQL DB. It is taking more than 20 minutes to retrieve all the data and writing it to text file. Can I use multi threading to reduce this fetching time and make the code more efficient. Any help will be appreciated.

I have used normal JDBC connection and ResultSetMetaData to fetch rows from the Table.

```
String row = "";
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from employee_details");
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
while (rs.next()) {
        for (int i = 1; i < columnCount; i++) {
            row = row + rs.getObject(i) + "|";// check
        }
        row = row + "\r\n";
    }
```

And I am writing the fetched values in text file as below.

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
    "C:/Users/430398/Desktop/file/abcd.txt"));
    writer.write(row);
    writer.close();
```

Comment: I don't think that multithreading will speed this up at all. Think of where and what the bottle neck is -- will threading affect this?

Comment: But there's no harm in trying it and seeing what happens -- what did you find with your experimentation with this?

Comment: I have tried using simple JDBC connection and resultmetadata to fetch the values. It is taking 20 minutes. I am not sure whether multi threading will work here or not

Comment: Again, I don't think so, since the bottle neck *I believe* is in fetching the data from the disk, and I don't see how threading will speed that up, but let's see what the experts have to say.

Comment: You can try a dummy test for example 5 thread reading from the database, taking IDs from 1-10000, 10001-20000 ... and see how much time will execute. If the disk is slow (the bottle neck) or something esle u will get the same result.

Comment: why all this trouble when mysql has built in data to export a query into a file???

Comment: @e4c5 Can you please let me know how can it be done?

Comment: please look up SELECT INTO OUTFILE

Comment: Could you please try to load the result of the query into memory without writing it into file? And use another data structure then String for the in-memory representation, e.g. List of List?

Comment: I think you need to identify where the bottleneck is. Is the bottleneck the sql query? Or the fetching of the rows via ResultSet? Or the building of the huge string? Or perhaps writing the file? Could you please try to identify that?

Comment: And one opinionated statement - I know that mileage might always vary but nevertheless I consider 20 minutes way too much to execute simple sql statement and fetch 50k+ rows, unless the DB is very far away. I would rather guess that the application is memory-starved - the row statement produces one new string for every column of each row, and during the processing these strings are getting bigger and bigger. Garbage collector has certainly lot of work to do.  But without having hard numbers this is only a guess.

Comment: The problem was with the building of huge String. I have used StringBuilder and the data is fetched within 2 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to identify where the bottleneck is. Is it the SQL query? Or the fetching of the rows via the ResultSet? Or the building of the huge string? Or perhaps writing the file?

You need to measure the duration of the above mentioned individual parts of your algorithm and tells us the results. Without this knowledge is not possible to tell how to speed the algorithm.

Comment: Fetching the data using ResultSet is taking much time than writing it into the file. I am thinking of using batches(using OFFSET) in SQL to reduce the fetch time.

Comment: Did you try the fetching WITHOUT building the huge string?

Comment: The problem was with the building of huge String. I have used StringBuilder and the data is fetched within 2 seconds.

Comment: I would then suggest that you accept my answer - I consider my answer actually canonical in given context, in a sense that it makes clear it has to be measured first before it can be optimized. And of course, that the measurement needs to make sure it is only one aspect beeing measured.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that rs.next will fetch Results from the DB in n-batches. Where n is a number defined by the JDBC-Implementation. I assume it's at 10 right now. So for every 10 batches it will again query the DB, hence there'll be an network-overhead - even if it's on the very same machine.

Just increasing that number will result in a faster loading time.

edit:
adding this
`stmt.setFetchSize(50000);`

might be it.

Be aware, that this results in heavy memory consumption.

Comment: I have tried adding stmt.setFetchSize(50000); but still it took 19 minutes to fetch the data.

Comment: @BasheerAhmed: but that's better than 20+ minutes.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sorry for the confusion. 20+ minutes was around 21 minutes and 45 seconds.

Comment: you might also have to play around a bit. You can set it to another number as well. try 1000 for the beginning.

Comment: Fetching more rows with one query should speed it up for sure.

Comment: The problem was with the building of huge String. I have used StringBuilder and the data is fetched within 2 seconds